# WebLogic ESS - Scheduler behaviour after an outage

Tags: weblogic, scheduled-tasks, soa

if we stop our ESS Scheduler Managed Servers for any length of time, when they are brought back they retrospectively trigger jobs. Is there a way to change this behaviour so that the schedulers will only pick up on the next schedules as opposed to trying to run all those missed during the outage?

For example - we have a schedule that fires every 2 minutes. If we bring down ESS Managed Servers between 12:00 until 14:00 - once the servers are back up, with their current configuration, the scheduler will trigger each of the jobs in the 12:00 to 14:00 outage window.

Is there a way to get the scheduler to pick up the next schedule after the server has resumed - for example 14:02 - and to ignore jobs which haven't been run during the outage window?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default behaviour.

To change this setting (assuming that you are wanting to edit and existing job):

In Enterprise Manager

- Edit Job Metadata > Job Definition;
- go to System Properties and add a key;
- Add the key for SYS_executePast and set it to false;
- Save the updated definition;
- Search for the Schedule;
- On the Action Menu Cancel the existing job;
- Back on the Action Menu choose Submit Like.